# Store List<Hashtable> in List<Hashtable> to return JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

I am using a WebMethod to return JSON object to JavaScript. I have been able to successfully do this with List. I now need nested List so I get:

```
{
    "SUCCESS":1,
    "USERS":[
        {"NAME":"Michael", "AGE":10},
        {"NAME":"Michael", "AGE":10}
    ]
}
```

MY CODE IN A NUTSHELL:

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
List<Hashtable> HashList = new List<Hashtable>();
List<Hashtable> HashListUsers = new List<Hashtable>();

ht.Add("SUCCESS", 1);
ht.Add("USERS", HashListUsers);
HashList.Add(ht);

return HashList;
```

I thought I could do this by storing List in the main List.

How else would I get nested JSON objects with a WebMethod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a view model:

```
public class Result
{
    public int Success { get; set; }
    public User[] Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

and then have a WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public Result Foo()
{
    return new Result
    {
        Success = 1, // a boolean seems more adapted for this instead of integer
        Users = new[]
        {
            new User { Name = "Michael", Age = 10 },
            new User { Name = "Barbara", Age = 25 },
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, instead of using a List<Hashtable> use a class. The properties of the class (Name, Age, etc.) would be serialized as nested JSON objects?

Comment: For the Users = new[]: How do I add users from a database? I am using a foreach(DataRow dr in dataTable.rows), looping through each record. How do I add this to a Users[] array?

Comment: @Michael C. Gates, you could use a `List<User>` instead of `User[]` if you want to dynamically add records. Then inside each iteration you will simply add a new element to the Users collection.

Comment: I'm close! I have: List<User> Users = new List<User>();
I successfully iterate through each, adding a user class to the list
But when I try to assign Users to the class.USERS[] like this: myUsers.USERS = Users; It says: Cannot implicitly convert type generic list <User> to User[]. What's that all about?

Comment: @Michael C. Gates, great, that's exactly how you should proceed. So on each iteration you should instantiate a new User class and assign it's Name and Age properties from your dataset or whatever and add this instance to the list.

Comment: All goes well. I can add it to the list, but when I try to assign the list to the class property User[], it throws that error. Any ideas? I thought I could assign the list directly like myClass.Users = Users (Users being my list of User classes...)

Comment: What error it throws, show the complete code you are trying to test, I cannot read your mind for Chris sake.

Comment: The error was on the previous post if you read it... and do you mean "Christ", or "Chris"? I'd like to meet this "Chris" fellow you mention... Anyway, I fixed it... Instead of doing public Users[] USERS{get;set;}, I had to do public List<Users> USERS{get;set;} in my class... is that right? It works, but it puts some funky stuff in front of the JSON output... __Type:Namespace.MyClass. No big deal as it doesn't affect the result.